# Implementing DLQ in Kafka using Spring Cloud Stream with Batch mode enabled

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to implement DLQ using spring cloud stream with Batch mode enabled

```
    @Bean
    public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer(BatchErrorHandler handler) {
        return ((container, destinationName, group) -> {
              if(dlqEnabledTopic.contains(destinationName))
                                    container.setBatchErrorHandler(handler);});
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchErrorHandler batchErrorHandler(KafkaOperations<String, byte[]> kafkaOperations) {
        CustomDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer = new CustomDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaOperations,
                (cr, e) -> new TopicPartition(cr.topic()+"_dlq", cr.partition()));
        return new RecoveringBatchErrorHandler(recoverer, new FixedBackOff(1000, 1));
    }
```

but have a few queries:

1. how to configure key/value Serializer using properties - my message is String type but KafkaOperations is using ByteArraySerializer
2. In the batch multiple messages are there , but if first message failed it went to DLQ but don't see the processing of next message.

**Requirement** - at any index if batch fails, I need only that message to be sent to DLQ and rest of the message should be processed again.

3. Is DLQ now supported with batch mode now ? just like with record mode it can be enabled using properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `spring.kafka.producer.*` properties - however, the DLT publishing should use the same serializers as the main stream app. `ByteArraySerializer` is generally correct.
2. The recovering batch error handler will perform seeks for the unprocessed records and they will be returned. Debug logging should help you figure out what's wrong. If you can't figure it out, provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the behavior you are seeing.
3. No; the binder does not support DLQ for batch mode; configuring the error handler is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks @Gary , I had to update the message before pushing it to dlq - so manually converted to byte[] and it worked.
We need to override DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer, can it be a @Component in spring context ?
`@Component
public class CustomDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer extends DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer {..}`


Also , during debugging - which took some time the message was polled again by the consumer.What is the suggested approach for these scenarios?

Comment: is there a way to skip a particular type of exception from retries in batch mode?

Comment: Yes, see the `addNotRetryableExceptions` or `setClassifications` methods. Regarding your first comment, you need to provide much more information; I don't see how the recovered message can be "polled again".

Comment: Thanks Gary , it worked. 

Is there a way to zip/compress DLQ messages in batch mode ?
Also in case there is some exception in the recoverer/handler , what should be done?

Comment: Just configure the producer's `compression.type`. If you want to compress the headers (e.g. stack trace), subclass the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` and override `createProducerRecord`. If recovery fails, the record will be redelivered again, as if the retries were not exhausted.

Comment: do we need to define brokers for dlq separately ?
Getting this error when msgs are trying to be pushed in DLQ - WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-3] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Comment: These are the properties I have defined :  - 
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=<msk broker url>
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=<msk zookeeper url>. Not sure from where it is taking localhost:9092

Comment: The `KafkaOperations` auto configured by Boot knows nothing about the binder properties. Use `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` (it will be used by the binder too, if there is no `...kafka.binder.brokers` property). `zkNodes` has not been needed for several years; the clients no longer connect to Zookeeper.

Comment: Thanks so much Gary, that issue is resolved but now getting Topic xxxx_topic_dlq not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

Comment: Deadletter topics are not created automatically by the publisher; you have to declare them manually, e.g. by adding a `NewTopic` `@Bean` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#configuring-topics) or using the `kafka-topics.sh` CLI. Boot automatically configures a `KafkaAdmin`.

Comment: The topic is there , have created it manually using kafka-topics.sh still DLQ is not able to find it

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; sorry. Does it have the same number of partitions as the original? Your destination resolver is routing to the same partition as the original one. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/#dead-letters for information about the destination resolver and how the destination partition is selected.

Comment: No Gary , the partitions are different .will try with same partitions once

Comment: it worked!!!! Thanks Gary